# Python 3.1 and win32api dll not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

Hello i got a clean python 3.1.3 install and then went for the latest version of pywin32 module from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/ but when i try to

```
import win32api
```

it gives me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import win32api
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

In english the last line is "The specified module can't be found". any ideas how to get pywin32 run on 3.1.3? what is this DLL that i need?

EDIT: fixed see comments below

Comment: Double check that you have a) got the right download for Python 3.1, and b) got the version matching whether your OS is 32 bit or 64 bit (64 bit downloads have `amd64` in the name).

Comment: @Thomas Don't you need to match the bit-ness of the Python that is installed rather than the bit-ness of Windows itself. Think 32 bit Python on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: @David: True - I'd skim-read the readme.

Comment: got it, 32 bit version for Windows 7 32 bit. The file is pywin32-215.win32-py3.1.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which of the files did you download and install? You need to install one of the installers, and not the source file (unless you can build it).

This can help to find which DLL it's trying to find: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I installed pywin32-215.win32-py3.1.exe downloaded directly from the project's page.

Comment: OMG nice, i used dependecywalker on C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom31.dll and it said that the file IEShims.dll was missing, a bit of google and i found it on C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer copied it to C:\Python31\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom31.dll and now import win32api works!! thank you so much